# Android resizing layout and dynamically position change

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, position

I am making a simple game and I have 2 questions:

**1. How to set that IamgeButton, ImageView and other elements resize depending on the screen size and resolution?**

Samsung Galaxy S4:

[image]

Prestigion 9.7 Pro:

[image]

**2. How can I change the postition of some element through code?** I tried with *setY* but it is not supported is lower APIs. I tried with this code, but it moves the whole activity content:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I am searching for some simple function like "margin" in CSS that is supported in 2.2 and higher APIs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use string.xml for various devices

Comment: How can I use string.xml for that? I used strings.xml to set strings like this: @string/app_name

Comment: string.xml is in no way helpful for solving this issue.

Comment: im sorry i mean dimensions.xml @user2627936

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you already use a RelativeLayout as your view root.

Now, just add the following to each of your ImageViews in your XML:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

This will make sure that your ImageViews are always displayed at the rightmost position.
Add an appropriate margin if you want a gap between the bounds of the screen and your ImageView, e.g.:

```
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
```

If you want to compensate for the vertical position change as well, you could add a LinearLayout, put all your ImageViews into that LinearLayout, set the same weight value for each ImageView and add the two lines above to the LinearLayout.

For making sure that all ImageViews have the same size on any screen density, you will have to create your images in different sizes and put them in the corresponding drawable folders (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi,...)

Images for hdpi devices will have to have 1.5x the size of the mdpi image to be displayed the same size, the factor for xhdpi is 2 and the factor for ldpi is 0.75. (The factor for mdpi is 1)

Moreover, you can create different layouts for different screen sizes or densities. This will provide the needed information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and tell if there are any problems.

Comment: im sorry i mean dimensions.xml @FD_